# Is there a way to have NumPy arrays calculate 0 * inf = 0 rather than 0 * inf = NaN?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I am using NumPy arrays to represent functions and probability distributions. I would like the arrays to obey the convention (common in probability) that `0 * inf` yields `0`.

I would like

- `array([1., inf]) @ array([1., 0.])` to yield `1.0`
- `array([1., inf]) @ array([1., 1.])` to yield `inf`

How might I do this? Is there a setting in NumPy that I can change? Should  I subclass the class `ndarray`?

EDIT---an idea:

```
class parray(np.ndarray):
    def __matmul__(self, other):
        return np.matmul(np.nan_to_num(self), np.nan_to_num(other))
```

EDIT 2---incorporating orlp's suggestion:

```
class parray(np.ndarray):
    def __matmul__(self, other):
        a = np.matmul(np.nan_to_num(self), np.nan_to_num(other))
        a[a > 1e90] = inf
        return a
```

Comment: You are correct. I'll edit the post!

Comment: Oh, good. Got me super confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to choose some big number (e.g. `1e100`) and use that to represent infinity.

Then you can do your computations (beware of `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered` to make sure your big number doesn't go back to `inf`), and if necessary convert anything above, say, `1e90` back to infinity.